# How do I convert XYZ coordinates to another projection system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, elevation

I am trying to convert between coordinate systems in QGIS.

I have a point file in NZGD49 coordinates (EPSG:27200) (referenced to the geoid) which I am trying to convert to NZGD2000 coordinates (EPSG:2193) (referenced to the ellipsoid).

I have tried saving the layer as a CSV file with the CRS set as NZGD2000 and the geometry set as AS_XYZ. This does a good job at converting the X and Y values, but returns 0 values for Z. I presume I have to assign which column represents Z before I do this but I don't know how. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: My understanding of NZGD49 and NZGD2000 are that they are both horizontal (only) and that the vertical datum hasn't changed (and so Z values shouldn't change).  We did a change between these two systems about 10-12 years ago and have not updated any Z values in the process.  There may be more to it, and it may be that it doesn't affect my data as it does yours, but it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: You need to confirm what type of Zs the NZGD49 data has. They should be orthometric heights, based on a particular vertical datum. NZ has had a few (see [this report](https://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=lastQuery&title=&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP Default With Code&title=nzvertical) ). Perhaps one covers your area. If so, you can likely keep your z's the same after converting to NZGD2K. Gravity-related Z's are not related to the horizontal CRS/datum--only when you want to convert them to ellipsoidal heights using a geoid model.

Answer (score 1):

How are the Z values measured?  Depending on what the z values are referenced to, you may be able to use them without 'reprojecting'.  If they are referenced to the ellipsoid, you'll need to recalculate them.  Here is an online calculator for this purpose:  http://apps.linz.govt.nz/coordinate-conversion/index.aspx?Advanced=1 
Here is a table of examples of height transformations: http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-services/coordinate-conversion/height-transformation-examples
Here is a list of calculations for transforming between ellipsoids:  http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/geodetic-datum-conversions/equations-used-datum

If you have access to FME I recommend using it to do the transformation.  Otherwise you will need to use one of the formulas found in the links to calculate your new Z coordinates.  You can write this into a python script, or calculate the values in excel and join the results back to the geometry in QGIS.

Comment: NZGD49 is referenced to the international 1924 ellipsoid whereas NZGD2000 is referenced to the WGS84. These ellipsoids differ by both their semi major axis and inverse flattening. My project involves tracking glacier volume changes over time (as a result of surface elevation changes), therefore it is necessary to have coordinates in the same coordinate system.

Comment: According to http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html, the shapefile must be of `POINTZ` type for 3D data. And according to http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html, the elevation must be of type real, not integer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in QGIS save as CSV dialog, under the Geometry heading there is a tick box 'Include z-dimension'.  Tick this box and select point.  From the layer options heading, select XYZ for the geometry.

Tested using QGIS 2.14.3 Essen